# Android network addresses

Tags: android, networking, emulation, adb, host

I have a tomcat web server running on my local machine. I also have a HTC desire and a Galaxy Tab. my problem is, I cannot connect from my real android device to my local machine. When I try to connect using the emulator, everything's fine. Emulator works with communication to the address: 
10.0.2.2, but the real devices don't

Does someone know the solution, or why there's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the exposed IP address of your local machine and connect to that. If you are behind a router, you will have to make sure that it allows the packets to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using network or WiFi? You should be on WiFi and connecting through the same router to have 10.0.2.2 accessible.

Also make sure you have your local machine's incoming port (I'm assuming 80) open and reachable from the outside.